# BufferedImage Sometimes Doesn't render

Tags: java, swing, awt, draw, bufferedimage

I have a class `MenuScreen` on which I paint a lot of images to. (4 at the moment [that may not be a lot to you but it is to me])

only one renders no matter what, sometimes they some half-render, and other times they completely render,

and sometimes they don't render at all (The main one still renders)

Here is my code

```
    public List<BufferedImage> im;

public MenuScreen() {
    setTitle("ALevelUp 0.0.1 Alpha");

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    initImages();
    JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 1));

    p.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(im.get(0))));

    add(p);
    setSize(766, 500);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
    System.err.println(getHeight() + "," + getWidth());

    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) im.get(0).getGraphics();
    draw(g);
}

public final void initImages() {
    im = a.init();
}

public final void draw(Graphics2D g) {
    BufferedImage s1 = im.get(1);
    Graphics2D s1g = (Graphics2D) s1.getGraphics();
    s1g.setFont(scale(a.getFont(), s1g, "Slot 1", s1));
    s1g.setColor(Color.black);
    s1g.drawString("Slot 1", s1.getWidth() / 2 - 23, s1.getHeight() / 2 + 7);
    g.drawImage(s1, (getWidth() / 2) - (s1.getWidth() / 2) - 21,
            47, rootPane);
    s1g.setColor(new Color(253, 198, 147));
    s1g.fillRect(106, 20, 100, 20);
    s1g.setColor(Color.black);
    s1g.drawString("Slot 2", s1.getWidth() / 2 - 23, s1.getHeight() / 2 + 7);
    g.drawImage(s1, getWidth() / 2 - s1.getWidth() / 2 - 21, 179, rootPane);
    s1g.setColor(new Color(253, 198, 147));
    s1g.fillRect(106, 20, 100, 20);
    s1g.setColor(Color.black);
    s1g.drawString("Slot 3", s1.getWidth() / 2 - 23, s1.getHeight() / 2 + 7);
    g.drawImage(s1, getWidth() / 2 - s1.getWidth() / 2 - 21, 311, rootPane);
}

public Font scale(Font f, Graphics g, String text, BufferedImage img) {
    float ntry = 20.0f;
    Font font = null;

    while (2 < 3) {
        font = f.deriveFont(ntry);
        FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics(font);
        int width = fm.stringWidth(text);
        if (width < img.getWidth()) {
            return font;
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me to understand why this happens and what I can do to fix it?

**Edit:** Here Are the image resources, if you need them:
[The Main Screen](http://i39.photobucket.com/albums/e151/PotatoPhil/ALevelUp/main_screen_neutral_zps9492a2fe.png)
[The Slot Panels](http://i39.photobucket.com/albums/e151/PotatoPhil/ALevelUp/main_screen_menu_slot_neutral_zpsd12b9fda.png)
[How it looks when it works](http://i39.photobucket.com/albums/e151/PotatoPhil/ALevelUp/Capture_zps6164aa33.png)

Comment: If you don't get help soon, consider creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where you condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles and runs, has no outside dependencies (such as need to link to a database), has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem. If you need to use images, please be sure that the images are available online.

Comment: and before anything to read [Oracle trail 2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html)

Comment: Don't use getGraphics, this is not how painting is done in Swing

Comment: First, accept that you don't have control over the paint process, second take a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

Comment: @MadProgrammer The Slots and everything are stationary, also I'm drawing on an image, not the Panel itself. I will use painting as soon as this project starts getting more complicated, but I don't feel Like I need to use it at this moment, Thanks for trying to help though :(

Comment: I'm going to spare myself the trouble and just use the Image of how it looks when it works Thank you to you all!

Comment: Don't forget to dispose of the images graphics context when your done with it (also, didn't realise you were using getGraphics was coming from a BufferedImage)

Comment: @MadProgrammer it's okay, I did mess up by gettting graphics from the JPanel once, but I corrected My mistakes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to modify most of the code to get something to work.  I'm assuming that this is what you want.

[image]

Here are the changes I made.

1. I added a main method that called SwingUtilities invokeLater to put the Swing components on the [Event Dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).
2. I split the code into 3 classes, DrawImage, DrawingPanel, and Snippet.  DrawImage creates the four images.  DrawingPanel draws the four images onto a JPanel.  Snippet creates the JFrame and adds the drawing panel to the JFrame.
3. I defined the size of the drawing panel to hold 4 slots.  I packed the JFrame so that
   the JFrame would be the correct size to hold the drawing panel.
4. I overrode the paintComponent method to draw the four images from the image list.  These images were already created in the DrawImage class.  I called super.paintComponent to make sure all of the Swing children components were drawn correctly.
5. I created the images before I created the Swing GUI.
6. I used a method I created, [centerString](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=602), to center the text in the images.  I left the scale method alone.

Here's the modified code.  Unlike yours, it's runnable.

```
package snippet;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.font.FontRenderContext;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Snippet implements Runnable {

    private JFrame frame;

    private List<BufferedImage> imageList;

    public Snippet() {
        imageList = new ArrayList<BufferedImage>();
        new DrawImage().createImages();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("ALevelUp 0.0.1 Alpha");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        DrawingPanel p = new DrawingPanel();
        frame.add(p);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        System.out.println(frame.getHeight() + "," + frame.getWidth());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Snippet());
    }

    public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 
                2535522354552193273L;

        public DrawingPanel() {
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(550, 350));
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            int x = 50;
            int y = 50;

            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                BufferedImage image = null;
                for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                    image = imageList.get(i * 2 + j);
                    g.drawImage(image, x, y, this);
                    x += image.getWidth() + 50;
                }
                x = 50;
                y += image.getHeight() + 50;
            }
        }
    }

    public class DrawImage {

        public void createImages() {
            imageList.add(createImage("Slot 1"));
            imageList.add(createImage("Slot 2"));
            imageList.add(createImage("Slot 3"));
            imageList.add(createImage("Slot 4"));
        }

        private BufferedImage createImage(String text) {
            Rectangle r = new Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 100);
            BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(r.width, r.height,
                    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

            Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
            Font font = g.getFont();
            g.setFont(scale(font, g, text, image));
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
            g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
            centerString(g, r, text, font);
            g.dispose();

            return image;
        }

        private Font scale(Font f, Graphics g, String text, 
                BufferedImage img) {
            float ntry = 20.0f;
            Font font = null;

            while (2 < 3) {
                font = f.deriveFont(ntry);
                FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics(font);
                int width = fm.stringWidth(text);
                if (width < img.getWidth()) {
                    return font;
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * This method centers a <code>String</code> in
         * a bounding <code>Rectangle</code>.
         * @param g - The <code>Graphics</code> instance.
         * @param r - The bounding <code>Rectangle</code>.
         * @param s - The <code>String</code> to center in the
         * bounding rectangle.
         * @param font - The display font of the <code>String</code>
         *
         * @see java.awt.Graphics
         * @see java.awt.Rectangle
         * @see java.lang.String
         */
        private void centerString(Graphics g, Rectangle r, String s,
                Font font) {
            FontRenderContext frc =
                    new FontRenderContext(null, true, true);

            Rectangle2D r2D = font.getStringBounds(s, frc);
            int rWidth = (int) Math.round(r2D.getWidth());
            int rHeight = (int) Math.round(r2D.getHeight());
            int rX = (int) Math.round(r2D.getX());
            int rY = (int) Math.round(r2D.getY());

            int a = (r.width / 2) - (rWidth / 2) - rX;
            int b = (r.height / 2) - (rHeight / 2) - rY;

            g.setFont(font);
            g.drawString(s, r.x + a, r.y + b);
        }

    }

}
```